# How can i document.getElementbyID of a variable?

Tags: javascript

I want to do a changing to certain `span` elements based in their `id`.

So i give each one of `div` and `span` an `id`, and then i try to `.style.color` each of the `span`.

but an error is to be seen : `Cannot read property 'style' of null"`

I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Here is a simple reproductible model of my program

```js
for (y = 0; y < 7; y++) {
  let colonne = document.createElement("div");
  colonne.className = "horaire_one";
  colonne.id = ("col" + y);
  for (x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
    let span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = "pasdispo_one_rpv";
    span.id = (colonne.id + x);
    document.getElementById(span).style.color = "green";
  }
}
```

Comment: You never add the span to the document so it can not access it. There is no need to do it since you already have it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing an id to document.getElementById, you're passing an element. Besides, it wouldn't work anyway, as you never added the element to the document. Fortunately, since you already have the element, you don't need to use document.getElementById. Simply do:

```
span.style.color = "green";
```

If you wanted to change `colonne` instead, simply replace `span` with `colonne`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to reference an element from the DOM before you add it to the DOM. You are not going to find it. You already have a reference to the span when you created it.

```js
for (let y = 0; y < 7; y++) {
  let colonne = document.createElement("div");
  colonne.className = "horaire_one";
  colonne.id = "col" + y;
  for (let x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
    let span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = "pasdispo_one_rpv";
    span.id = colonne.id + (x + y * 26);
    span.style.color = "green";
    span.textContent = x + y * 26;
    colonne.appendChild(span);
  }
  document.body.append(colonne);
}
```

```css
.pasdispo_one_rpv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 1.4em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here:

1. creating element is not enough. You need to add it to the DOM somehow. Google for 'appendChild'
2. `document.getElementById(span).style.color = "green";` it should have span.id in the brackets

And just a note:

3. No need for `document.getElementById(span).style.color = "green";` in your code, because `span` is already in a loop. You can change to `span.style.color = 'green';`